# Python mock how to edit the returned value of a mocked function

Tags: python, mongodb, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I have a function in a separate file and unittest in a different file, my goal is to get the actual return value of the function and edit it.

`my_module.py`

```py
def function_to_test(a,b,c)(arg1,arg2,arg3):
    data_to_send = Mongoclient.find({_id:'arg1'})
    return data_to_send

def another_function():
    """Do something."""
    value_to_be_used = function_to_test(a,b,c)
    another_function_call_in_another_module(value_to_be_used)
```

`test_file.py`

```py
class Mytest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        # return_value is based on the original return value, 
        # and should vary based on the original returned value
        with patch(my_module.function_to_test, return_value='new data'):  
            my_module.another_function()
```

The new data is the original data + some edits to the original data.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: How does `another_function` interact with `function1` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can keep a reference to the original function.
- And then you can define your patched function that calls the original one and adds some data.
- And then you can use your patched function as a `side_effect` for your mock.

```py
class Mytest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        # the return_value is based on the original return value and
        # should vary based on the original returned value

        original = my_module.function_to_test

        def patched(arg1, arg2, arg3):
            original_result = original(arg1, arg2, arg3)
            return original_result + ' @ new data'

        with patch("my_module.function_to_test", side_effect=patched):
            result = my_module.another_function()

        assert result == 'old data @ new data', result
```

```py
def function_to_test(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    return 'old data'


def another_function_call_in_another_module(value_to_be_used):
    return value_to_be_used


def another_function():
    # Do something
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
    value_to_be_used = function_to_test(a, b, c)
    return another_function_call_in_another_module(value_to_be_used)
```

Some references:

- `side_effect`:
  https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect
- `patch`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch

Comment: is there a way I can change the 'new data' as well programtically for different test cases?

Comment: like defining different `patched` functions in each test ? or like changing `new_data` depending on the result of `original` ?

Comment: changing new_data based on parameters that I can send to the function.  Also in the first line where  you are assigning original to function1 the arguments that are supposed to present are missing.

Comment: The original function is supposed to recieve arguments that are prsent only in my_module.py  file

Comment: Oh, the arguments are not lost when you copy the reference to the original function. I've updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: It worked excellent answer thanks. If you could you provide links where I can learn more about mocks, the main documentation page doesn't cover cases like this.

Comment: The info is all in those docs, but you need to put together information from different sections: how to pass a function as `side_effect` and how to keep a reference to the un-patched function. That is more or less implied by the `patch` docs, but yeah, no examples.